# getting all the data of input file into variable using java. something like undef($/) in perl

Tags: java, io

i was trying to get whole data of input file into a variable. Is there a way to get it in a single or many statements. I had worked with scanner but it has only next() and nextLine() which splits with whitespace and newline delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) [FileUtils.readFileToString()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29).

(Commons also has a `readFileToString` that takes an encoding, and a `readFileToByteArray`.)

Answer (score 0):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `com.google.common.io.Files` has `static byte[] toByteArray(File file)` and `static String toString(File file, Charset charset)`.  (If charsets are annoying, see `com.google.common.base.Charsets`.)